# window.open width ignored in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

I want to create a popup of a fixed size, however the width attribute is ignored in Chrome. But Works fine in FF.

Here's my code:

```
window.open('','','width=300');
```

The resultant popup is larger than the given width.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to provide height?

Comment: yes, I've tried providing height. No change in result.

Comment: Strangely its works when u have a height attribute. See http://jsfiddle.net/YrRZu/

Comment: my apologies. Adding height does work! I was in full-screen mode last time I tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tried to put this one on Chrome version 25.0.1364.172

```
window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
```

and it correspond the exact height and width of the window.

to check, please use

```
window.innerHeight; //to display height
window.innerWidth; //to display width
```

Comment: I didn't realize the parameters had to be passed in some weird non-object format!

Comment: @BT that's what the documentation is for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#windowfeatures

Comment: Yes Christian, documentation helps. But having documentation doesn't solve the problem that this is a garbage api design.

Answer (score 11):

it would seem to be some bizarre quirk in Chrome, that you have to specify **both** a width and a height to get it to observe the dimensions set. If you only specify a height, or a width, then that single dimension is ignored. Hence why in the other answer it worked fine for Jeff.