# Setting iframe width with iframe.style.width not working

Tags: javascript

im opening a new file dynamically within an iframe and im trying (with no success), to set the opening iframe with a fixed width with:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// tried this guy
iframe.style.width = 970 + 'px';

// tried this guy
iframe.width = 970 + 'px';

// tried this guy
iframe.setAttribute('width', '970px');


window.open(url, iframe);
```

but with no success, the iframe always opens with 1200 width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFRAME is a part of the page "inline-frame" you cannot open it via "window.open". You *can* append it to your current document, e.g.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.style.width = '970px';
iframe.src = url;

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

If you really meant to open a new window - just  pass window specs as the 3rd parameter of `window.open`:

```
window.open(url, "mywindow", "width=970");
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that both `iframe.style.width` and `iframe.width` would work? Which one is preferred?

Comment: @NULL I've always used CSS style. I think it's preferable to attribute.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work on chrome? The spec says it doesnt support it

Comment: My bad for not reading the specs properly, feel like an idiot now.

Comment: @FernandoFleury No problem :) glad I was able to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471657/window-open-width-ignored-in-chrome

and found this fix for chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en' xml:lang='en'>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type='text/JavaScript'>
function bigger() {
    var objIframe = document.getElementById( 'testiframe' );
    if ( objIframe != null ) {
        objIframe.width = ( parseInt( objIframe.width, 10 ) + 20 ) + 'px';
        } //if
return;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="testiframe" src="." width="800px"></iframe><br />
<br />
<span onclick="bigger();">[CLICK TO EXPAND]</span><br />
</body>
</html>
```